# Запрос MySQL выдает неправильный результат

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

В моей базе данных есть таблички:

- fact с полями F_code, F_date, F_hours, F_rate, E_code, Pr_code (Номер факта, Дата, количество отработанных часов, фактическая стоимость часа, код работника, код проекта);
- employee с полями E_code, E_name, S_code (код работника, имя работника, код специальности);
- project с полями Pr_code, Pr_name, E_code (Код проекта, название проекта, код курирующего проект работника);
- speciality с полями S_code, S_name, S_rate, S_hours (код специальности, название специальности, предполагаемая стоимость часа, предполагаемое необходимое к отработке количество часов)

Мне нужно было создать запрос, чтобы получить количество специальностей, фактически задействованных в каждом проекте. Попытка была такой:

```sql
select count(distinct employee.S_code) as num from fact 
inner join employee on fact.E_code = employee.E_code
inner join project on fact.Pr_code = project.Pr_code 
inner join speciality on employee.S_code = speciality.S_code
where fact.E_code = employee.E_code and employee.S_code = any(select speciality.S_code from speciality)
and fact.Pr_code = exists (select project.Pr_code from project);
```

Ответ это чудо выдает, но не вполне верный. Пишет 3, хотя при подсчете вручную у меня вышло, что есть лишь одна удовлетворяющая условию специальность. Не могу понять, в чем ошибка и как ее исправить.

Comment: А можно полюбопытствовать, нахрена нужны условия во WHERE, полностью дублирующие условия связывания? И нахрена таким гениальным образом проверять, что таблица не пуста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  p.`Pr_code`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.`S_code`)
FROM
  project p
  JOIN fact f ON (f.`Pr_code` = p.`Pr_code`)
  JOIN employee e ON (e.`E_code` = p.`E_code`)
GROUP BY
  p.`Pr_code`
```